# Saltstack - how to watch a whole directory for changes?

Tags: salt-stack

```
nginx
  pkg.installed:
    - name: nginx
  service:
    - name: nginx
    - running
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/*

/etc/nginx:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://{{slspath}}/etc/nginx/
    - include_empty: True
```

How can I make the above work? 
I want to make it so that every time a new config is added in /etc/nginx/conf.d/newsite.conf nginx is reloaded.

Currently I can only achieve that if I manually add every conf in the sls in the manner:

```
/etc/nginx/conf.d/newsite.conf:
  file.managed:
   - source: salt://{{slspath}}/etc/nginx/conf.d/newsite.conf
```

Is there a way to automate it?

Comment: Have you looked into incron as an alternative?

Comment: Yeah I know about inotify, but this is different, I want to apply changes to 20 servers and only if there was a change in nginx folder reload the service. I could do a incron on each server, but I also want the output and everything to go through saltstack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't watch a file change within a directory to execute a state. But you can watch a state result to do so. In your case, the following should restart `nginx` whenever a change is done by the `/etc/nginx` file state:

```
nginx
  pkg.installed:
    - name: nginx
  service.running:
    - enable: True
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx

/etc/nginx:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://{{slspath}}/etc/nginx/
    - include_empty: True
```